# MVC DropDownListFor selected item not binding due to property name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have found a little edge case for when the DropDownListFor will not bind the value in the viewmodel to the list.

The below code will NOT bind the value.

ViewModel

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public Title? Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TitleSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Person()
    {
        return View(
             new PersonViewModel
             {
                 Title = Title.Mrs,
                 TitleSelectList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Title)),
             });
    }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, Model.TitleSelectList, "Please select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the property name fixes this.

Change the viewmodel to `public Title? TitleTesting { get; set; }` and update the rest of the code to match it will work.

I would be interested to know if this is a bug or a reserved word.

Comment: Possible conflict with `ViewBag.Title`